# R: flatten tabular hierarchy

Tags: r

I have data similar to this, where `fruit` is the topmost level, `color` is the second level and `quality` is the third level of the hierarchy:

```
data.frame(
 Level = c("fruit", "color", "quality", "fruit", "color", "color", "fruit", "color", "quality", "quality", "fruit", "fruit"), 
 Tag = c("apple", "red", "normal", "pear", "yellow", "green", "peach", "orange", "normal", "abnormal", "banana", "avocado"), 
 Value = 1:12)
```

How to flatten the hierarchy to a table where hierarchy levels are columns, from left to right? The result in this case should be:

```
data.frame(
 fruit=c("apple", "pear", "pear","peach", "peach","banana", "avocado"),
 color=c("red","yellow", "green", "orange", "orange", "", ""),
 quality=c("normal","","", "normal", "abnormal", "",""), 
 Value = c(3, NA, NA, 9, 10, NA, NA))
```

---

**Test data**:

```
structure(list(Level = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Tag = structure(c(5L, 
7L, 6L, 16L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 14L, 17L, 7L, 88L, 21L, 88L, 19L, 7L, 
18L, 21L, 18L, 23L, 18L, 46L, 20L, 7L, 18L, 22L, 18L, 23L, 18L
), .Label = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "ascot", "AUD", "Australia", 
"availableCash", "B", "BB", "BBB", "Brazil", "C", "CAD", "Canada", 
"CCC", "cfd", "CHF", "China", "CNH", "CNY", "commonShare", "convertibleBond", 
"corporateBond", "corporateBondTotalReturnSwap", "corporateCds", 
"corporateCdx", "defaultedCorporateBond", "Denmark", "discountNote", 
"DKK", "dr", "equityFutureCfd", "equityOption", "equityTotalReturnSwap", 
"equityVarianceSwap", "EUR", "European Union Member State", "exchangeTradedFund", 
"frn", "fxForward", "fxOption", "GBP", "Germany", "governmentBond", 
"HKD", "Hong Kong", "IDR", "ILS", "indexFuture", "indexOption", 
"India", "Indonesia", "INR", "interestRateSwap", "Ireland", "Israel", 
"Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "JPY", "Kazakhstan", "KRW", "Luxembourg", 
"Malaysia", "Multinational", "mutualFund", "MYR", "New Zealand", 
"NOK", "Norway", "Not Applicable", "Not Available", "Not Rated", 
"NZD", "Philippines", "PHP", "PLN", "Poland", "Portugal", "preferredShare", 
"SEK", "SGD", "Singapore", "South Africa", "South Korea", "sovereignCds", 
"Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "THB", "Total", 
"TWD", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", 
"USD", "ZAR"), class = "factor"), Value = c(-2427544.452063, 
-2375655.354498, -2375655.354498, -51889.0975650001, -51889.0975650001, 
3733.69460778798, 3733.69460778798, 3733.69460778798, -213296.649672231, 
-73289.5744459406, -73289.5744459406, -140007.07522629, -140007.07522629, 
205101731.9733, 2238511.58321064, 2238511.58321064, 104126150.859062, 
104126150.859062, 98737069.5310267, 83011916.6708533, 15725152.8601734, 
30968975.3531842, 11349121.3053863, 11349121.3053863, 14796021.271866, 
14796021.271866, 4823832.77593178, 4823832.77593178)), .Names = c("Level", 
"Tag", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L
))
```

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself?

Comment: Tried to restructure the ill-defined hierarchy with `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::separate` (http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/), for example having aggregate `fruit.color.quality` factor with levels "apple.red.normal" etc.

Comment: Unclear to me how Value works in the output. Why does the 1st item (red apple) have Value = 3, but the next two items have NA?

Comment: @arvi1000 To be precise, "apple.red.normal" has Value=3. Note that row "apple.red.abnormal" doesn't exist, so "apple.red.abnormal"=NA. Think of `Value` as subtotal. If any subcategory is missing, subtotal cannot be calculated. Therefore, "apple.red"= "apple.red.normal"+ "apple.red.abnormal" = 3 + NA = NA

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Level = c("fruit", "color", "quality", "fruit", "color", "color", "fruit", "color", "quality", "quality", "fruit", "fruit"), 
  Tag = c("apple", "red", "normal", "pear", "yellow", "green", "peach", "orange", "normal", "abnormal", "banana", "avocado"), 
  Value = 1:12)

final <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=(length(unique(df$Level))+1)))
names(final) <- c(as.character(unique(df$Level)), "Value")

index <- which(df$Level==names(final[1]))
index2 <- which(df$Level==names(final[2]))
index3 <- which(df$Level==names(final[3]))

diff <- diff(index)
diff[length(diff)+1] <- nrow(df)-index[length(index)]+1


row <- torow <- 0

for (i in 1:length(index)) {
  row <- torow+1
  torow <- row+max(table(df$Level[index[i]:(index[i]+diff[i]-1)]))-1

  # Assign fruit
  final[row:torow,1] <- as.character(df$Tag[index[i]])

  # Assign color
  if (length(df$Tag[index2[which(index2>index[i]&index2<index[i+1])]])>0) {
    final[row:torow,2] <- as.character(df$Tag[index2[which(index2>index[i]&index2<index[i+1])]])  
  }

  # Assign quality
  if (length(df$Tag[index3[which(index3>index[i]&index3<index[i+1])]])>0) {
    final[row:torow,3] <- as.character(df$Tag[index3[which(index3>index[i]&index3<index[i+1])]])  
  }

  # Assign Value
  if (length(df$Tag[index3[which(index3>index[i]&index3<index[i+1])]])>0 & 
      length(df$Tag[index2[which(index2>index[i]&index2<index[i+1])]])>0) {
    final[row:torow,4] <- as.character(df$Value[index3[which(index3>index[i]&index3<index[i+1])]])  
  }
}
```

Comment: there has got to be a more parsimonious way to do this

Comment: Thanks, but throws error on the test data (see edit). In addition, the solution is not scalable to number of levels different than 3.